# Easy question about set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have 2 sets and am wondering what B actually is.

A = {a, b} and B = {A}

Does B = {a, b} or B = {{a, b}}

Comment: $B = \{ \{ a, b \} \} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is a set that consists of another set $A$ therefore $B = \{A\} = \{\{a,b\}\}$ hence why there are two brackets instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

$B = \{\{a,b\}\}$

Think about it literally: $A$ is the set containing $a$ and $b$.

$B$ is the set containing $A$.

So it makes sense to say that $B$ is the set containing the set containing $a$ and $b$. $\Rightarrow B=\{\{a,b\}\}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $B = \{a, b\}$ then $A = B$. How do $A$ and $B$ differ when $B = \{\{a, b\}\}$?